# Android CameraX get current exposition, focus, etc

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I want to disable all automatics, so I can get stable signal from camera

I've tried to lock AE, AWB, Black level color in 5 seconds after camera start

```
.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, true)     
.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.BLACK_LEVEL_LOCK, true)                                            
.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_LOCK, true)
```

It works on Pixel 4a, but doesn't work on Galaxy S7 with enabled flash - Galaxy S7 doesn't locks AE (when flash is disabled it works). I've tried to set

```
setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF)
```

it works on S7, but it doesn't on Pixel 4a. Pixel sets exposure to minimum and I see almost black screen.

```
setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_OFF_KEEP_STATE)
```

Works the same

Now I want to try to set CONTROL_MODE_OFF_KEEP_STATE and set current exposition, so it will be locked manually. But I can't find method to get current exposition, I only can get SENSOR_INFO_EXPOSURE_TIME_RANGE

So, my question is

**Is it possible to get current exposure, focus, sensitivity, etc at runtime?**

Answer (score 0):

The solution is `Camera2Interop.setSessionCaptureCallback`
Parameter `result: TotalCaptureResult` in `onCaptureCompleted` contains all required data

```
val builder = ImageAnalysis.Builder();
val camera2InterOp = Camera2Interop.Extender(builder)
camera2InterOp.setSessionCaptureCallback(object : CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                override fun onCaptureCompleted(session: CameraCaptureSession, request: CaptureRequest, result: TotalCaptureResult) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result)
                    if (!delayedParamsApplied && System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > 5000) {
                        delayedParamsApplied = true
                        try {
                            val bundleBuilder =
                                    CaptureRequestOptions.Builder()
                                            .setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, true)
                                            .setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.BLACK_LEVEL_LOCK, true)
                                            .setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_LOCK, true)

                            getFocusDistance()?.let {
                                bundleBuilder.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, it)
                            }
                            result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME)?.let {
                                bundleBuilder.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, it)
                            }
                            result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY)?.let {
                                bundleBuilder.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, it)
                            }
                            result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION)?.let {
                                bundleBuilder.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION, it)
                            }


                            bundleBuilder.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_OFF_KEEP_STATE)
                            bundleBuilder.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF)
                            val bundle = bundleBuilder.build()
                            cameraControl.captureRequestOptions = bundle
                        } catch (t: Throwable) {
                            Timber.e(t)
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: which version are you using? am trying to do in java, but facing problem with `ExtenderBuilder`

Comment: @Balasubramanian 1.1.0-alpha07